# Autocomplete function works just in open script tag and not in the same tag in ajax.done function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

Here's the code:

```
    var components = new Array();
    $("#types").change(function() {
        $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          url: "/index.php/field/get-fields-by-type/" + $("#types").val(),
          dataType: "json"
        }).done(function( data ) {
            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                var dat = data[i];
                components.push({ value: dat.name, data: dat.id });
            }
            //HERE I GET: TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
            $('#productfield-field_id').autocomplete({
                lookup: components,
                onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                    alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
                    $("#productfield-field_id").val(suggestion.data);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    // BUT HERE it works like charm and does the functionality which it should be doing
    $('#productfield-field_id').autocomplete({
        lookup: components,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
            $("#productfield-field_id").val(suggestion.data);
        }
    });
```

I want to know the reason. Why Im getting that TypeError message about autocomplete in $.ajax.done function but when it's just in script tag plain open then it works and does the functionality with no errors. And how can I solve this problem so I could add those components to lookup

I've debugged so far and I can tell that components has value in proper style formatted and jQuery selecting #productfield-field_id is also valid and can find it. Tried for example adding value to it and it worked.

Im using this autocomplete: https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/
And I also tried to replace autocomplete with "devbridgeAutocomplete" and the results are the same. Works in open but not in ajax.done function.

I've also tried to make alternative solution that putting the plain open code into just standalone javascript function which takes array as parameter and tried to call autocomplete function in that. But then I get that TypeError too.

Also jQuery and Autocomplete is included to webpage.

Browsers I've tried: Firefox & Chrome

Comment: because in done function you are not in global scope that can not reach autocomplete function

Comment: Can you suggest some alternative solutions how to get that collection to lookup attribute or how can I make this reachable?

Comment: can you make js fiddle example that i can help

Comment: Not sure if you ment that. Cause heard about js fiddle for the first time atm but here is some link: https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/16637/